# A question on " But guess we'll cry come first of May "

Tags: lyrics

In the lyrics of First of May, there is a line "But guess we'll cry come first of May". What is the meaning of it? Especially, what is the meaning of "come first of May"? What will "come first of May"?

Thanks

Comment: The question is technically off-topic since it's about music lyrics, but it's a reasonably valid question otherwise.  Not something that is easily revealed with a bit of research, unless the person is somehow aware of some cultural implication.

Comment: See [Is "come September" a kind of inversion?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/24834/is-come-september-a-kind-of-inversion)